# How to use getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() with flutter for web

Tags: flutter

I'm a beginner in flutter, i want to use SQlite database using sqflite package in my Flutter App,
I'm running my flutter app on chrome because I have the emulator not working, I use `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` in the code and i have an error saying :

`Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)`

I read in a post:
I ran into this after starting to add web support to an application. The getApplicationDocumentsDirectory function only supports iOS and Android (docs). I added a check for web and changed the way I set the directory which fixed the "No implementation found for method" for me.

To tell if the platform is web use Flutter's kIsWeb:

```
Then handle setting the directory accordingly:

if (kIsWeb) {
    // Set web-specific directory
} else {
    appDocumentDirectory = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
}
```

but i don't know how to Set web-specific directory.

My code is

````
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }
    _database = await _initializeDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> _initializeDatabase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, 'annonce_database.db');
    return await openDatabase(path, version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }```
````

Answer (score 6):

getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() doesn't works on Web, so using your code, you have to modify th _initializeDatabase() function, and replace with a String path route in order to use it in Web (i.e. assets folder inside the project)
Don't forget to import KIsWeb

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
...
Future<Database> _initializeDatabase() async {
//here
    if (kIsWeb) {
        String path = "/assets/db";
    } else {
        Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String path = join(directory.path, 'annonce_database.db');
    }
    return await openDatabase(path, version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue.

```
Web Build Error:  Uncaught (in promise) Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
```

**Actual Code**

```
final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  // Initialize hive.
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  // Register Adapters.
  Hive
    ..init(appDocDir.path)
    ..registerAdapter(ActivityAdapter())
    ..registerAdapter(ActivityTypeModelAdapter());
```

**After Fixing it with kIsWeb**

```
var path = "/assets/db";
if (!kIsWeb) {
  var appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  path = appDocDir.path;
}

// Initialize hive.
await Hive.initFlutter();

// Register Adapters.
Hive
  ..init(path)
  ..registerAdapter(ActivityAdapter())
  ..registerAdapter(ActivityTypeModelAdapter());
```

[image]